# Docker X11 issue with OSX -- $DISPLAY

Tags: python, macos, docker, x11, xquartz

I am running OSX Sierra, and am trying to run 4 simulations and one graph for a model.  It uses Docker that is supposed to return graphical results in an X11 window.
However, I've done a lot of research, and have found the following suggestions that don't work on their own:
-check the $DISPLAY to make sure its blank or cleared
-reinstall XQuartz
-Change XQuartz security settings to be taking network permissions
-modify ifconfig

Below is the current output:

INFO       simconf data:        time_sim=4      plotting=1

```
******************************************************************************
This program contains Ipopt, a library for large-scale nonlinear optimization.
 Ipopt is released as open source code under the Eclipse Public License (EPL).
         For more information visit http://projects.coin-or.org/Ipopt
******************************************************************************

INFO       Iteration 0 from 4
INFO       Iteration 1 from 4
INFO       Iteration 2 from 4
INFO       Iteration 3 from 4
INFO       Plotting
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 27, in <module>
    main()
  File "main.py", line 23, in main
    simulator_1.simulate()
  File "/app/src/algorithms/Envio-Algorithm-Tools/mpc_casadi/dmpc/../mpc_sim_tools_casadi/simulator_file.py", line 162, in simulate
    mpc_sim_tools.plot(self.dmpc_sim_data.data_list[index_mpc], fig_settings)
  File "/app/src/algorithms/Envio-Algorithm-Tools/mpc_casadi/dmpc/../mpc_sim_tools_casadi/mpc_sim_tools.py", line 8, in plot
    fig = mpcplot(mpc_data.x.T, mpc_data.u.T, mpc_data.d.T, mpc_data.tplot, fig_dict=fig_settings)
  File "/app/src/algorithms/Envio-Algorithm-Tools/mpc_casadi/dmpc/../mpc_sim_tools_casadi/mpc_sim_tools.py", line 43, in mpcplot
    fig = plt.figure()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 548, in figure
    **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 161, in new_figure_manager
    return cls.new_figure_manager_given_figure(num, fig)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/_backend_tk.py", line 1044, in new_figure_manager_given_figure
    window = Tk.Tk(className="matplotlib")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1876, in __init__
    self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't connect to display "127.0.0.1:0.0"

The key issue appears to be in here: 
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't connect to display "127.0.0.1:0.0"
```

Here are the related commands I ran before:

export DISPLAY=127.0.0.1:0.0

docker create -it -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix --name algorithm-tools-3 python-algorithm-tools-3

Grateful for all help!